# How would I add a mute timer to my Discord bot? (Discord py)

Tags: python

How would I be able to make it so that I can add a timer to my mute? Would I need a database or something?

```
@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member):
 if ctx.message.author.server_permissions.manage_roles:
    role = discord.utils.get(member.server.roles, name='Muted')
    await client.add_roles(member, role)
    await client.say("**{0}** was muted by **{1}**!".format(member, ctx.message.author))
 else:
    await client.say("You don't have permission to use this command.")
```

that's the code. What would I need to add/modify to be able to do like, !mute  ?

Answer (score 1):

To time the comment, basically add the option to have a `mute_minutes` parameter and add a timer. The nice thing about asynchronous programming is that this will not mean your control flow just stops for the timer duration. Not sure if this is the best option, but that's how I use it in my bot, couldn't find a better one.
The code:

```
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import discord

@commands.command()
async def mute(self, ctx, members: commands.Greedy[discord.Member],
                   mute_minutes: typing.Optional[int] = 0,
                   *, reason: str = "None"):
    """Mass mute members with an optional mute_minutes parameter to time it"""

    if not members:
        await ctx.send("You need to name someone to mute")
        return

    muted_role = discord.utils.find(ctx.guild.roles, name="Muted")

    for member in members:
        if self.bot.user == member: # what good is a muted bot?
            embed = discord.Embed(title = "You can't mute me, I'm an almighty bot")
            await ctx.send(embed = embed)
            continue
        await member.add_roles(muted_role, reason = reason)
        await ctx.send("{0.mention} has been muted by {1.mention} for *{2}*".format(member, ctx.author, reason))

    if mute_minutes > 0:
        await asyncio.sleep(mute_minutes * 60)
        for member in members:
            await member.remove_roles(muted_role, reason = "time's up ")
```

This is written for discord.py version 1.0, so you might need to adjust here and there. But the basic idea is that you simply `await asyncio.sleep`, releasing the control flow back to the event loop for that time, and afterwards invoke an unmute command. 
I also added some sanity checks and you should check for permissions as well.